# Tomcat 7: "setenv.sh" vs "/etc/default/tomcat7" to update JAVA_OPTS

Tags: java, tomcat, configuration, tomcat7, jmx

I wish to update the `JAVA_OPTS` used by Tomcat 7 to enable JMX monitoring.

When I look at the internet I see 2 primary ways to do it:

1. Using **"setenv.sh"** [The popular way]
2. Update **"/etc/default/tomcat7"**

Now which is the recommended way to do this? What are the advantages and disadvantages of each?

Comment: Related for Ubuntu 9: http://serverfault.com/questions/139435/where-to-set-java-heap-options-e-g-xmx-for-tomcat-6-under-ubuntu-9-04

Answer (score 1):

`setenv.sh` is the recommended way.
The advantage is closest path to manipulate. Also whenever you need to deploy multiple apps with different conf you can set each app different `setenv.sh`.
For example for me I am serving 3 apps: first folder calling serverA pointing in conf by `CATALINA_BASE=/var/tomcat/serverA`.

Here is a sample code `catalina.sh` reading all setenv to set memory as their conf.

```
path:// Enviroment/tomcat/serverA/bin/setenv.sh

#!/bin/sh
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java
JAVA_OPTS="-Djava.awt.headless=true -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
-server
-Xms1256m
-Xmx1256m
-XX:NewSize=256m
-XX:MaxNewSize=256m
-XX:PermSize=256m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-XX:+DisableExplicitGC
-XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled"
CATALINA_HOME=/var/tomcat
CATALINA_BASE=/var/tomcat/serverC
export JAVA_HOME JAVA_OPTS CATALINA_HOME CATALINA_BASE
```